# Hadwiger–Nelson problem 5 colors needed if color sets are Lesbeauge measureable

Tags: reference-request, combinatorial-geometry

Where can I find a reference to the result that if the plane is colored in 4 colors, so that the set of colors of the same kind is measurable for each color, then there is a set containing 2 of distance 1?

Comment: I assume [the references on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) don't contain those proofs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result was proved by Kenneth J. Falconer. The reference is

> [MR0629593 (82m:05031)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=629593). Falconer, K. J. *[The realization of distances in measurable subsets covering $R^n$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316581900145?via%3Dihub).* J. Combin. Theory Ser. A **31** (1981), no. 2, 184–189.

The argument is relatively simple, you need a decent understanding of the Lebesgue density theorem, and some basic properties of Lebesgue measure, and the proof makes use of a theorem of D. G. Larman and C. A. Rogers. The write up is fairly dense, though, and filling in all the details takes some work.

A more recent presentation of the proof can be found in

> [MR2458293 (2010a:05005)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2458293). Soifer, Alexander. **[The mathematical coloring book. Mathematics of coloring and the colorful life of its creators](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387746401)**. With forewords by Branko Grünbaum, Peter D. Johnson, Jr. and Cecil Rousseau. Springer, New York, 2009. xxx+607 pp. ISBN: 978-0-387-74640-1.

If you are not familiar with Soifer's book, I recommend it. It is uniquely idiosyncratic, but charming and full of interesting mathematics. Falconer's theorem is discussed in Chapter 9, "Measurable chromatic number of the plane", pp. 60–66. He writes: "I found his 1981 publication [Fal1] to be too concise and not self-contained for the result that I viewed as very important. Accordingly, I asked Kenneth Falconer, currently a professor and dean at the University of St. Andrews in Scotland, for a more detailed and self-contained exposition. In February 2005, I received Kenneth's manuscript, hand-written especially for this book, which I am delighted to share with you."

---

In a remarkable recent development that supersedes Falconer's result, Aubrey de Grey has found a finite set of points in $\mathbb R^2$ with chromatic number 5, meaning that if a color is assigned to each point, and only 4 colors are used, then there are two points of the same color at distance 1 from each other. De Grey's graph has 1581 vertices.

> ArXiv:1804.02385. *[The chromatic number of the plane is at least 5](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385)*. Aubrey D.N.J. de Grey, preprint.

This number has since been improved, see the page for Polymath 16 [here](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Hadwiger-Nelson_problem), in particular the table in section 2.